# Switching tabs in Gedit 3.* with the mouse wheel

Tags: gedit

I use Gedit a lot and thus tend to have a lot of tabs open at any one time. In Gedit 2.* I could switch between tabs using my mouse wheel but since Oneiric I can't. I assume this is because of various GTK "upgrades".

Does anybody know of a plugin (or workable fix -- that doesn't require me to recompile everything and its brother) that will see me back to mousewheeling my day away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be the answer you want to hear, but it looks like changing tabs with the mouse wheel was [removed in gtk+](https://markmail.org/message/a473nphirej5znhz).